# DataGridView Right Click Specific Column for ContextMenuStrip

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

With C# I am trying to only show a `ContextMenuStrip` (CMS) when I right click a specific column in my `DataGridView`.  I am confused as to whether I should be using a `DataGridView_CellContentClick` and/or `dataGridView1.HitTest()`.  Then to finish off my problem I want to send the data from that right clicked cell to a new form window.

My current code has strange behavior.  It will not show the CMS unless I have first left click or right clicked the 4th column.  However once I have it will always show the CMS on a right click.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 4)
        {
            //Create the ContextStripMenu for Creating the PO Sub Form
            ContextMenuStrip Menu = new ContextMenuStrip();
            ToolStripMenuItem MenuOpenPO = new ToolStripMenuItem("Open PO");
            //Assign event handlers
            MenuOpenPO.MouseUp += new MouseEventHandler(MenuOpenPO_Click);
            Menu.Items.AddRange(new ToolStripItem[] { MenuOpenPO });
            //Assign created context menu strip to the Datagrid
            dataGridView1.ContextMenuStrip = Menu;
        }
    }

    void MenuOpenPO_Click(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var ht = dataGridView1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);

               MessageBox.Show("Hello2");
               PO_Form POWindow = new PO_Form();
               POWindow.Show();
    }
```

I was going to use the `var ht = dataGridView1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);` to grab the cell value.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

**Edit 1**
So I updated dataGridView1_CellContentClick to this and it gets me very close to the behaviour I am looking for.  If I first left click in column 4 **then** right click I get my CMS.  If I left click any other cell in another column then right click the CMS is no longer there.  However I want to be able to just right click a cell in column 4 without having to left click first to create the CMS.

```
        private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 4)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show("Hello1");
            //Create the ContextStripMenu for Creating the PO Sub Form
            ContextMenuStrip Menu = new ContextMenuStrip();
            ToolStripMenuItem MenuOpenPO = new ToolStripMenuItem("Open PO");
            //Assign event handlers
            MenuOpenPO.MouseUp += new MouseEventHandler(MenuOpenPO_Click);
            Menu.Items.AddRange(new ToolStripItem[] { MenuOpenPO });
            //Assign created context menu strip to the Datagrid
            dataGridView1.ContextMenuStrip = Menu;
        }

        else
            dataGridView1.ContextMenuStrip = null;
    }
```

Comment: I don't really get what you want? What data do you want to get from the cell which the mouse is right-clicked at?

Comment: I want the ContextMenuStrip (CMS) to only show if the 4th column is right clicked.  Then I want to be able to click "Open PO" from the CMS and have the data from that right clicked cell sent to a new windows form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my own problem and so will post the solution.  Unfortunately I am very new at C# programming and really extremely rusty at it in general.  I struggled with the concept of Event handlers (not sure if correct name?), how they were being called and how they all vary depending on if you are using MouseEventArgs, EventArgs, KeyEventArgs, etc.  Anyway I digress.

My solution is below.  I found the using `dataGridView1.MouseUp` gave me poor user interaction results requireing 2 of each action for a state change.  IE create my ContextMenuStrip when the correct coloumn is right Clicked.  Or make it disappear if any other column is right clicked.  So use `dataGridView1.MouseDown` for better results.

```
    dataGridView1.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(this.dataGridView_MouseDown);

    private void dataGridView_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            var ht = dataGridView1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);

            if (ht.ColumnIndex == 4)
            {
                //Create the ContextStripMenu for Creating the PO Sub Form
                ContextMenuStrip Menu = new ContextMenuStrip();
                ToolStripMenuItem MenuOpenPO = new ToolStripMenuItem("Open PO");
                MenuOpenPO.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(MenuOpenPO_Click);
                Menu.Items.AddRange(new ToolStripItem[] { MenuOpenPO });
                //Assign created context menu strip to the DataGridView
                dataGridView1.ContextMenuStrip = Menu;
            }

            else
                dataGridView1.ContextMenuStrip = null;
        }
    }
```

If you want to create a new form or do something else I used the following code when clicking your ContextMenuStrip I used the following after creating this event handler? `MenuOpenPO.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(MenuOpenPO_Click);`

```
    void MenuOpenPO_Click(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
       PO_Form POWindow = new PO_Form();
       POWindow.Show();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I did this in VB ..

```
Private Sub DGV_CellMouseClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) Handles DGV.CellMouseClick
    If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right Then

        DGV.CurrentCell = DGV.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex)

        CMS.Show(DGV, DGV.PointToClient(Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position))

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: The OP tagged his question as of C#, why do you think this answer is OK?

Comment: @KingKing .. that why I said first 'In VB' .. just hope Matt can get the idea .. and I never mention that my answer is OK ..

Comment: Unfortunately I am not a very strong programmer and only do so on the rare occasion, but I find it interesting and enjoyable.  To go from one language VB which I have no experience with to C# wont help me a great deal.  My first problem is to figure out if I should be using a datagridview event to limit when the contextmenustrip shows up or if I can do it with the datagridview HitTest to achieve that result.

Comment: @Matt .. you can use cellmouseclick event .. and I just suggested you some idea here ..